# Swift 3.0: How to call CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()?

Tags: swift, cgimage, swift3, xcode8-beta3

I need to implement this Objective-C code in Swift 3.0 (I'm using Xcode 8 Beta 3):

```
// Note: this code comes from an Obj-C category on UIImage
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, cropRect);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];
```

I can't find anything in the latest documentation for `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When I write this code in Xcode8's Swift editor:

```
let imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage!, cropRect)
```

Swift has shown me an error as:

```
error: 'CGImageCreateWithImageInRect' has been replaced by instance method 'CGImage.cropping(to:)'
```

So, I changed the line to:

```
let imageRef = self.cgImage!.cropping(to: cropRect)
```

And the second line of your code seems to be directly convertible to Swift:

```
let image = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
```

And the latest documentations of `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`,

[CGImageCreateWithImageInRect](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1454683-cgimagecreatewithimageinrect?language=objc)

Clicking the Swift link, it shows:

> ```
> func cropping(to rect: CGRect) -> CGImage?
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageRef = self.image.cropping(to: cropRect)
```